# How to change and move an image using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

This is my very first post here... well, what I need is to move an image over the screen using 4 keys on my keyboard and changing the image for every key eg:

--W--
A-S-D
When I press "D" key, my object should move to the right, and my image should be "facingright"
When I press "A" key, my object should move to the left, and my image should be "facingleft" and so it goes...

****EDIT : here is how my project is after your help! thanks!!!: http://xonny.esy.es/Xonnygame/index.html


I had this code over here, but it seems impossible to do something like I want, so I need to modify it!

```
<html>
<head>

<title>Moving an Image</title>

<script language="JavaScript">

function moveObj(name, Xpix, Ypix) 
{
    obj = document.getElementById(name);

    px = parseInt(obj.style.left) + Xpix;
    py = parseInt(obj.style.top) + Ypix;
    obj.style.left = px;
    obj.style.top = py;
}

function ProcessKeypress(e)
{
    var myObj = "mario";
    var moveBy = 10;

    if (e.keyCode) keycode=e.keyCode;
    else keycode=e.which;
    ch=String.fromCharCode(keycode);

    if(ch=='a' || ch=='A')      moveObj(myObj, -moveBy, 0);
    else if(ch=='d' || ch=='D')     moveObj(myObj, moveBy, 0);
    else if(ch=='w' || ch=='W')     moveObj(myObj, 0, -moveBy);
    else if(ch=='s' || ch=='S')     moveObj(myObj, 0, moveBy);
}

</script>

<body onKeyPress="ProcessKeypress(event);">

<p><img id="mario" style="z-index: 0; left: 300px; position: absolute; top: 250px" 
    height=72 width=100 align=baseline border=0 hspace=0 src="mario right.jpg"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'd recommend clicking the code button after highlighting the entire block of code; the backticks are meant for in-line code only. Like this: `some code goes here`, etc.

Comment: So what is it doing or not doing? Are you getting errors? Please provide more information about the problem you are having.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be your final code. In the body you add this:

```
<body onkeydown="keydown(event)" onkeyup="keyup(event)">
```

And the js would be something like this

```
var movUp=false, movDown=false, movLeft=false, movRight=false;

function moveMario() 
{
    obj = document.getElementById("mario");
    px = parseInt(obj.style.left);
    py = parseInt(obj.style.top);
    var moveby=5;

    if(movUp) py=py-moveby;
    if(movDown) py=py+moveby;
    if(movLeft) px=px-moveby;
    if(movRight) px=px+moveby;

    if(movUp&&!movLeft&&!movRight&&!movDown) obj.src='mario_up.png';
    if(!movUp&&movLeft&&!movRight&&!movDown) obj.src='mario_left.png';
    if(!movUp&&!movLeft&&movRight&&!movDown) obj.src='mario_right.png';
    if(!movUp&&!movLeft&&!movRight&&movDown) obj.src='mario_down.png';

    if(movUp&&movLeft) obj.src='mario_up_left.png';
    if(movDown&&movLeft) obj.src='mario_down_left.png';
    if(movUp&&movRight) obj.src='mario_up_right.png';
    if(movDown&&movRight) obj.src='mario_down_right.png';

    if(!movUp&&!movLeft&&!movRight&&!movDown) obj.src='mario.png';


    obj.style.left = px;
    obj.style.top = py;
}

function keydown(e){
    ch=String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode).toLowerCase(); // toLowerCase() so we don't have to check for 'a' and 'A';
    moveby=5;
    if(ch=="a") movLeft=true;
    if(ch=="s") movDown=true;
    if(ch=="d") movRight=true;
    if(ch=="w") movUp=true;
}

function keyup(e){
    ch=String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode).toLowerCase();
    moveby=5;
    if(ch=="a") movLeft=false;
    if(ch=="s") movDown=false;
    if(ch=="d") movRight=false;
    if(ch=="w") movUp=false;
}

setInterval("moveMario()",30);
```

Each time a direction key is pressed, we set that direction to true. Each 30 miliseconds, the function moveMario() is called, and it will move the image to the direction(s) that are set to true, and also change the image to those directions.

By the way, in your html code you never closed the head tag. Be careful with that.

Comment: thanks for the help! I can't manage to work, check my code please!
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7111ab3b64243e3d62d3

Comment: I don't see anything inside the body. You forgot to place your mario image there. Also, your script code is in nowhere. You should place it on the header or at least on the body.

Comment: working as intended now! :) thanks alot! now I gotta use some imagination to make a game,, will need help prolly with 2 objects colliding or something like shooting a projectile from my "yoshi"
here is how it is now... https://gist.github.com/anonymous/68c597c181578b66df92

Answer (score 1):

*Sample(Click on the image first, to make sure you are in the right canvas before press any key):*
http://jsfiddle.net/leojavier/f8kp6auc/

```
<img id="item" style="width:100px; height:100px; cursor:pointer; position:relative; left:10px; top:20px;" src="http://www.adobe.com/business/calculator/VIP/image/loader.gif" alt="">
<script>
(function(){

        item = document.getElementById("item");

        function move(x){
            var currentPositionX = parseInt(item.style.left);
            var currentPositionY = parseInt(item.style.top);
            console.log(currentPositionY);
            switch(x){
                    case "left":
                    item.style.left = currentPositionX - 15 + "px";
                    break;
                    case "right":
                    item.style.left = currentPositionX + 15 + "px";
                    break;
                    case "up":
                    item.style.top = currentPositionY - 15 + "px";
                    break;
                    case "down":
                    item.style.top = currentPositionY + 15 + "px";
                    break;
            }

        }


        window.addEventListener("keydown", key, false);
        function key(e){
            switch(e.keyCode){
                case 65:
                //LEFT
                move('left');
                break;
                case 68:
                //RIGHT
                move('right');
                break;
                case 87:
                //UP
                move('up');
                break;
                case 83:
                //DOWN
                move('down');
                break;
            }
        }
    })();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create two Mario images, one facing right an another facing left, and switch between them;

```
if(ch=='d' || ch=='D'){
    moveObj(myObj, moveBy, 0);
    document.getElementById(myObj).src="mariofacingright.png";
}
```

And so with the left. Also, if you want the animation to go smoothly, you should use keydown and keyup instead. Keydown should create an interval that moves the image each X and keyup removes the interval. That way your animation would be smooth and you could move it up and left at the same time.

Comment: thats it! I have all the images... one for each(left, right, front, back and a default) default would be when hes not moving.. I just dont know how to switch between them... do you know any example of a keydown/keyup ? will try now what you just told me and see if it works! ty!